# MVC5 Client Side Validation not kicking in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, client-side-validation

So I have gone through tons of questions here on Stack Overflow and verified just about everything I can think of and I can't get client side validation to work.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

To shorten the question, the original code was removed as a more simplified example is provided below.

EDIT:

I am editing this question to try and remove confusion and get to the root of the problem.  So to make this very simple here is what I have done on my project:

Step 1: Created a new TestController

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet, AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TestViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(TestRequestModel requestModel)
    {
        if (!@ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new TestViewModel
            {
                Email = requestModel.Email
            };
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Step 2: Created a new TestView

```
@model MyProject.Models.TestViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title =  "User Console Home";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
}
```

Step 3: Created a new TestRequestModel

```
public class TestRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Step 4: Created a new TestViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Step 5: Ensured Web.Config contains proper keys

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Step 6: Ensured my _Layout.cshtml contains the right javascript files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

7. Compared my project to a brand new one that has client validation working, and the code is almost identitcal

What am I missing?  Out of the box I should not need to write an adapter to get Required or EmailAddress Attributes working.  I feel like there is a setting or a piece of code that I am missing, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Is your `GetClientValidationRules()` method even being hit?

Comment: @StephenMuecke as far as I can tell it is not.  I had a breakpoint on it and rebuild the website just to make sure and no it was not hit.  However, the server side validation runs fine.

Comment: You have completely changed the question, but Reza Aghaei is correct - the model in the view is `TestViewModel` which does not have any validation attributes applied to its `Email` property so therefore there are no `data-val-*` attributes generated for that property and therefore no rules are added to `jquery.validate`, Just add the `[Required]` and `[EmailAddress]` attributes to the `Email` property in `TestViewModel` and you will get client side validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model which you used for the *View* is `TestViewModel`

```
@model MyProject.Models.TestViewModel
```

But you didn't decorated the `Email` property of `TestViewModel` with validation attributes, so change your view model to this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: Client-side validation will be used in rendered view which you created using `TestViewModel`. So to enable client-side validation, you need to decorate its properties with validation attributes. These validations don't have anything to do with `TestRequestModel` which you used as input of `POST` action. The attributes which you set on `TestRequestModel` will be hit after posting data to server when model binding.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, I will test your theory tonight and reply how it went.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I'll do some more testing over the weekend with a clean example again as I only tested this on my regular models.

Comment: No problem, if you follow steps of enabling client-side validation, it will work. Don't worry. The main problem of your code was what I mentioned in answer.

Comment: What you wrote was absolutely correct, however, in my case, it was only half of the problem.  In the quick example above I am not showing that I am using interfaces, I had that in the original question (section that I removed when I wrote the example).  The interfaces are referenced by the View.  So even when I added the attirbutes to my concrete ViewModel classes, it was still not working because the Interfae View Model doesn't have the attributes.  In order to solve my problem I had to add the attributes on the interfaces too.

Comment: I didn't read the post before edit. I didn't test interfaces myself, Good point. I'll also test it with interfaces wen I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me in a new project. I have just changed the **TestViewModel** model.Other codes are same.The model you are sending to view by `return view(model)` and the model that you are using in your view i.e. `@model MyProject.Models.TestViewModel` should be same for the client validation to work.

```
public class TestViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Either you change the *TestViewModel* as I did or use *TestRequestModel* in you view and change your index method's return statement to *return View(new TestRequestModel());*

If it does not work drag your js files directly in your page and test either js(s) is/are loading or not.

Comment: Thank you for that, however, what you wrote is not necessarily true.  You can reuse validation such as e-mail by specifying email like I did in the client side validation.  I actually had that code working at one point, I just do not know what on earth changed for it to stop working.

Comment: I have updated my question to remove the confusion from the Custom Validation